# Good habits of initiating pages in framework

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am creating test framework.

Is it good if I initiate all pages of my site in @BeforeClass in class which is extended by Testcase classes?

```
public class ConfigurationForBrowser {
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void browserSetup() throws Exception{

    this.driver = getDriver(DriverFactory.getBrowserTypeByProperty());

    registrationPage = 
    PageFactory.initElements(driver,RegistrationPage.class);
    homePage = 
    PageFactory.initElements(driver,HomePage.class);
 ...

}
```

or is it better if in every Test case I have:

```
public class Test extends ConfigurationForBrowser {
RegistrationPage registrationPage;

@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void setup() throws Exception{
    registrationPage= RegistrationPage.initElements(driver, RegistrationPage.class);

@Test
 ....

}
```

Or maybe there is some better way to get rid of BeforeClass in every testcase?

Comment: This is all a matter of preference. Personally, I always have `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)` in the constructor of my Page class.

Comment: I did as you said but I have null pointer exception:                       
       public MainPage(WebDriver driver){
        super(driver);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SiKing mentioned in the comments, I have found calling **PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this)** in the constructor is the way to go, that way you aren't initializing classes unnecessarily and you don't require the BeforeClass stuff.

Some C# code that I have handy, should get the point across:

```
public class HomePage
{
    private readonly IWebDriver _driver;

    public HomePage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "login")]
    public IWebElement LogInButton { get; set; }

    public LoginPage ClickLogin()
    {
        LogInButton.Click();

        // Page object chaining, you could use a void return type instead
        return new LoginPage(_driver);
    }
}
```

Then in your test:

```
[Test]
public void TestLogin()
{
    // Elements get initialized in the constructor, so you don't have to call it explicitly
    var homePage = new HomePage(Driver);

    var loginPage = homePage.ClickLogin();

    loginPage.Login("username", "password");

    Assert.True(someCondition);
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, it works! I even put it in my BasePage super class, so I do not have to initiate it in every of pages! so i think it is a good idea otherwise correct me as I am pretty new in Test automation..

Comment: @Dawid no problem.  I have done the same with a base class.  I just removed that from my example to keep it simple.